# Can we disable/enable tooltip dynamically in Livecharts?

Tags: wpf, tooltip, livecharts

I am using Livecharts in wpf to generate a multiple line chart. The number of lines can be varied from 1 to 30.

For now, I have added a default tooltip which displays all the y-axis values of the current x-axis position where cursor is hovered. So when I have 36 lines in the chart, a larger tooltip is displayed and it does look bad.

So, can I know whether there is any approach which we can enable the tooltip only when the number of lines is lesser that 10 (for an example) and disable when it is above 10?

Thank you!

Comment: i think you could do that with the binding, but without code its difficukt to describe an idea